# Handling concurrent requests when counting webpage hits on a Python webserver

Tags: javascript, python, webserver, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm creating a view counter for my webpage. The idea is that if you are hitting my webpage any number of times in a day, the view count should be increased by 1.

I'm using cookies to achieve this:

```py
is_viewed = request.cookies.get('viewed')
if is_viewed:
    return response

add_view_in_db()
response.set_cookie('viewed', True)
return response
```

This code will work in normal scenarios, however, if N concurrent requests are sent from a device, the view count will be increased by N.

One solution is logging every incoming request and filtering out repeated requests using some kind of browser fingerprinting & timestamp but it doesn't feel like the perfect solution.

Is there a better way to make sure that a view count is only increased by 1, regardless of any number of requests in a given period, concurrent or sequential.

Stack: FastAPI, uvicorn, sqlalchemy, PostgreSQL